# How can I speed up the task of pasting data in Excel from a PDF file?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, copy-paste, pdftotext

I have many PDF files with huge paragraphs and I need to copy only the relevant text and paste it in specific columns in an Excel sheet. For example:
a) Copy 'Runny nose, cough, sneezing' and paste it under 'Symptoms' column in Excel
b) Copy 'Rhinovirus' and paste it under 'Causes' column in Excel
c) Copy 'Wash your hands thoroughly and often with soap and water for at least 20 seconds. If soap and water aren't available, use an alcohol-based hand sanitizer that contains at least 60% alcohol.' and paste it under 'Prevention' column in Excel.

In summary, the required text to be copied is a mix of single words and long phrases.

My current method is to manually copy the text and paste in the specific Excel cells. In order to save some time, can I use a tool that allows me to highlight the text, select the tag and appends the text in an excel sheet in the backend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try to use Excel Power Query to open the pdf and then search by key words.
You can find a detailed walkthrough here
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/searching-for-text-strings-in-power-query
Hope it helps. I would like to post this as comment, not an answer, but I cannot do it yet.

Comment: If it is an answer it is perfectly fine to post it as an answer and not as comment. That way the OP can accept the answer if it helped solving his problem, which in turn helps other people having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @JakobStark !

Comment: Thanks for your response @SKuan. Per my understanding, this is a process to search for substrings in larger text. But I do not know the text strings to put in excel columns before hand and I am selecting and copy those as I read through the PDF. The more I am researching about it, the more I think I need an annotation tool. Something that data scientists use to create sentence pairs for their models.